What is the correct way to use a utility class in React?
For example, I have a utility class here.
1
The original intention of designing it as a utility class is because there are time-consuming operations to be done during initialization. And in the page, it only needs to repeatedly call the function renderBtn.
Now, I want to use this class in a function component. What would be a good way to initialize it?
enter image description here
Should it be initialized outside of this function component, inside but not as a state variable, or as a state variable?
I want this utility class to be loaded once when entering this function component for the first time, and not to load its initialization method at other times.
Just some basic coding style I want to ask, nothing wrong.

have a look at [ask], especially the part about not posting images of code

It depends on what is the meaning of this utility class, if it can be shared between different components, it is fine to put it outside. Otherwise it should be stored by useRef or useMemo hook. store it as a state may not a good choice because you are not seems to plan to "refresh" it every time
